# pandas dataframe aggregate based on json data

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a bunch of data saved as json strings in Pandas DataFrame. I'd like to aggregate the DataFrame based on json data. Here's some sample data:

```
data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'name': ['geo1', 'geo2', 'geo3'],
    'json_data': [
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [10, 20, 30]}',
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2005], "val": [50, 60, 70]}',
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [80, 90, 85]}'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'd like to aggregate by `year` and calculate the `median` of val. So, if the data were a column, it would be something like:

```
dff = df.groupby(['year'], as_index=False).agg({'val':'median'})

print(dff)

year val
2000 50
2001 60
2002 58
2005 70
```

In case of even #, round up the median. only integer values, no decimals.

Comment: I think you might have a problem with parsing JSON. Can you show us how you get the JSON?

Answer (score 2):

First convert JSON as string to dictionary and load as pandas dataframe

```
import json

df = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(item) for item in data['json_data']])
```

Then, [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) into rows and [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with the respective operation

```
df.explode(['year', 'val']).groupby('year')['val'].median().round().astype(int)
```

Output

```
year
2000    50
2001    60
2002    58
2005    70
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract year and val from json_data, then group by year to get the result.

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'name': ['geo1', 'geo2', 'geo3'],
    'json_data': [
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [10, 20, 30]}',
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2005], "val": [50, 60, 70]}',
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [80, 90, 85]}'
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
result = (df['json_data']
    .apply(json.loads)
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(zip(x['year'], x['val'])))
    .stack()
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .groupby(0)[1]
    .median()
    .apply(lambda x: int(round(x)))
    .reset_index()
    )
result.columns = ['year', 'val']
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   year  val
0  2000   50
1  2001   60
2  2002   58
3  2005   70
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired aggregation and median calculation you will first convert the JSON strings in the `json_data` column to actual Python dictionaries. Then, explode the dictionaries to create multiple rows for each `year` and `val` pair. Lastly, you will group by `year` and calculate the rounded up median of `val`:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import math

data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'name': ['geo1', 'geo2', 'geo3'],
    'json_data': [
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [10, 20, 30]}',
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2005], "val": [50, 60, 70]}',
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [80, 90, 85]}'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert JSON strings to dictionaries
df['json_data'] = df['json_data'].apply(json.loads)

# Create an empty DataFrame to store the exploded data
exploded_data = []

# Iterate through rows and explode the data
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    id_value = row['id']
    name_value = row['name']
    json_data = row['json_data']
    for year, val in zip(json_data['year'], json_data['val']):
        exploded_data.append({'id': id_value, 'name': name_value, 'year': year, 'val': val})

exploded_df = pd.DataFrame(exploded_data)

# Use groupby to calculate the median and round up
dff = exploded_df.groupby('year', as_index=False)['val'].median()
dff['val'] = dff['val'].apply(math.ceil)  # Round up median

print(dff.to_string(index=False))
```

Here is the output:

```
year  val
2000   50
2001   60
2002   58
2005   70
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the elements in json_data from string to dictionary and append them to a dataframe

---

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'name': ['geo1', 'geo2', 'geo3'],
    'json_data': [
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [10, 20, 30]}',
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2005], "val": [50, 60, 70]}',
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [80, 90, 85]}'
    ]
}

data_list = data.get('json_data')
df_list = list()
for el in range(len(data_list)):
    str_to_dict = json.loads(data.get('json_data')[el])
    df = pd.DataFrame(str_to_dict)
    df_list.append(df)
dfs = pd.concat(df_list)
   

dff = dfs.groupby(['year'], as_index=False).agg({'val':'median'})
dff.val = dff.val.apply(np.ceil).astype(int)
print(dff)
```

---

```
OUTPUT
   year  val
0  2000   50
1  2001   60
2  2002   58
3  2005   70
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
from ast import literal_eval

out = (pd
   .json_normalize(df['json_data'].apply(literal_eval))
   .explode(['year', 'val'])
   .groupby('year', as_index=False)['val'].median()
   .round().astype(int)
 )

print(out)
```

Alternative with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) (likely more efficient):

```
import json

out = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(json.loads(s))
                  for s in df['json_data']])
         .groupby('year', as_index=False)['val'].median()
         .round().astype(int)
 )
```

Output:

```
   year  val
0  2000   50
1  2001   60
2  2002   58
3  2005   70
```

Answer (score 0):

More explicit steps, for an easier to follow approach:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'name': ['geo1', 'geo2', 'geo3'],
    'json_data': [
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [10, 20, 30]}',
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2005], "val": [50, 60, 70]}',
        '{"year": [2000, 2001, 2002], "val": [80, 90, 85]}'
    ]
}
# Convert from JSON
data['json_data'] = [json.loads(x) for x in data['json_data']]

# Load into the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Extract your columns
df['year'] = df.json_data.str.get('year')
df['val'] = df.json_data.str.get('val')

# Drop the excess Column
df = df.drop("json_data", axis=1)

# Explode the extracted Columns
df = df.explode(["year", "val"])

output = df.groupby(['year'], as_index=False).agg({'val':'median'})
print(output)
```

Output:

```
   year   val
0  2000  50.0
1  2001  60.0
2  2002  57.5
3  2005  70.0
```